# Publish nested object to Redis

Tags: python

Don't know how much this actually has to do with Redis, I think it's a gap in my understanding of Python.

If I have a dictionary whose value is a simple value, this works fine:

```py
obj = {'key': 'value'}
redis.publish('ch', obj)
```

But if the dictionary has a value that is a dictionary, it fails:

```py
# from the console in debug mode:
>>> {key: value}
{'tray_info': b'{"rows_count":0,"columns_count":0}'}
>>> redis.publish('ch', {key: value})
TypeError: Argument {'tray_info': b'{"rows_count":0,"columns_count":0}'} expected to be of bytearray, bytes, float, int, or str type
```

I am able to get redis to publish if I convert the dict value to a string:

```py
if isinstance(value, bytes):
    v = value.decode('utf8')
    message = json.dumps({key: v})
else:
    message = json.dumps({key: value}).encode('utf-8')
redis.publish('ch', message)
```

but then the published message has a value that is a string, the stringified version of the dictionary.

In my JS client I would then have to turn it back into a JSON, and I'd have to somehow check to see if my value was a "legitimate string" or if it was meant to be a JSON, and it gets ridiculous.

I imagine there's something relatively simple about python I'm missing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types), Redis does not supported nested maps:

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values